# how can i use the variable of a for loop in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple function in a `for` loop. I want when I choose one of the `select` elements, an alert displays and tells me the value that I have chosen.
But the argument `i` of the for loop doesn't work.
What's the problem?

```
<select id="s1">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

for(i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
$("#s"+i).change(function()
{
    var sValue = $("#s"+i).val();
    alert(sValue);
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why...oh...why are you binding your event listeners in a loop?

Comment: I do that for to don't repeat my function for 100 time in my javascript file

Comment: You can bind your event using a jQuery collection as in Tasos Fel's answer. No need to use a loop and less code.

Comment: i don't know how to do that i'm not a very expert in jquery can you give an exmple for that please

Comment: Tasos Fel already gave you an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114134/746736

Comment: i see it but i am working for a big work than what you saw in the exmple ..and my question is just an exmple to get help..the real exmple is not like that..in the real exmple i use a lot of Different id..so i need something like the (let) to make the variable i in the loop global...but when i do that it invokes this syntax error: missing; after for-loop initializer..i don't find an answer for this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is declaring that variable using the statement `let` to get it work.

> The `let` statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>


<script>
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    $("#s" + i).change(function() {
      var sValue = $("#s" + i).val();
      alert(sValue);
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Or, just simply use the `this` context:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>


<script>
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    $("#s" + i).change(function() {
      var sValue = $(this).val(); // <--- HERE
      alert(sValue);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: :The let way is the good for me but you have in your code just a small error you have to but this ;  after your for loop ..because if you don't put a ; your code whill work..but there are an error in it......thank you brother

Answer (score 1):

Try his :

```
   $('select').on('change', function(){
       alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  $("#s" + i).change(function() {
    var sValue = this.value || 0;
    alert(sValue);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
<option value="choose">choose</option>
<option vaue='1'>1</option>
<option vaue='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: very powerful and easy and fast answer..i thank you with my deep heart...true answer